# Apache Camel 2.19 REST Component - No double quote in JSON body (getIn processor)

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, apache-camel

i have trouble with Rest component from Camel 2.19.1, i try to post a JSON on /test like `{"hello":"world"}`

When i try to obtain the JSON object from the body, i obtain a String without double quote `{hello:world}`.

With my ObjectMapper i have the error: `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('h' (code 104)): was expecting double-quote to start field name` because i don't have double quote.
How can i obtain correctly the JSON object from the Body inside a processor ?

```
        rest("/test")
            .post("/send").description("Post test")
            .to("direct:test");


        from("direct:test").process(new Processor() {
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                log.info("body: " + exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                String input = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                try {
                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    JsonNode actualObj = objectMapper.readTree(input);
                    log.info("Object: "+actualObj);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    exchange.setException(e);
                }
            }
        }).end();
```

Thanks to help me,
Regards

**@UPDATE**

Finally it's working well.

The main problem came from ServletConfiguration (from CamelConfiguration file where i configure my CamelContext):

```
 @Bean
CamelContextConfiguration contextConfiguration() {
    return new CamelContextConfiguration() {
        @Override
        public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext context) {
            context.getRestConfiguration().setBindingMode(RestConfiguration.RestBindingMode.off);
            context.getRestConfiguration().setComponent("servlet");
        }

        @Override
        public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {

        }
    };
}
```

`RestConfiguration.RestBindingMode` was `json`, with `off` it's working well...

http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are sending a valid json? I have not seen this problem before.

Comment: Although you have found a solution (which seems odd to me), may I ask how you've sent data to your service? Via curl? The `bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)` is used if you want Camel to automatically marshal the request to a certain POJO object (i.e. `.outType(ListResponse.class)`) though you can also unmarshal it manually on using `.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, JSONPayload.class)` where this class is a simple POJO class that can have additional Jackson annotations like `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` or `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it's working well.

The main problem came from ServletConfiguration (from CamelConfiguration file where i configure my CamelContext):

```
 @Bean
CamelContextConfiguration contextConfiguration() {
    return new CamelContextConfiguration() {
        @Override
        public void beforeApplicationStart(CamelContext context) {
            context.getRestConfiguration().setBindingMode(RestConfiguration.RestBindingMode.off);
            context.getRestConfiguration().setComponent("servlet");
        }

        @Override
        public void afterApplicationStart(CamelContext camelContext) {

        }
    };
}
```

`RestConfiguration.RestBindingMode` was `json`, with `off` it's working well...

http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the mapping behavior by providing it a configuration like this:

```
objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true)
```

Comment: I tried but now i have this error (on '=' character) : `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('=' (code 61)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value`

Answer (score 0):

For a random reason I fail to understand some `Camel` default decides that the right way to unmarshal a JSON request is automagically a `LinkedHashMap` and that is what your body will be. If you retrieve it as `String` some (other?) part of camel magic calls `toString()` on the body-map which will look as you describe it.

Switching this off the way you did it obviously solved your problem at hand, but I think there should be a better way to solve this an a per-request basis, but I have so far failed to find it.